# Issues with table printing in IE9

Tags: javascript, css

css style for printing is as below

```
<style>
 @media print {
        max-width: 900 px ;
        #tableContainer {height: 100% !important;}
        #programTable tr {display: table-row !important; }
        #tableContainer {overflow: visible !important;}
    }
    </style>
```

Here program table is the table id and tableContainer is the div that holds the table which has a fixed height.There are some hidden rows in the table which I want to print
Now have a print button which just calls windows.print(). 
In IE8 and Chrome, when I click on windows.print(), all the contents of the table are printed properly. BUt the behaviour is not the same in IE9.
In IE 9 the hidden rows in the table are not printed.

Do anyone knows a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width: 900 px ;` <-- this declaration has no selector.

Comment: I removed that and still the issue persists.

Comment: If you want 100% height, you'll need: body, html { height:100% }

Comment: yes I did this..As I said it works fine in IE8 and Chrome but not in IE9.